# get div left and right value using jquery

Tags: jquery

There is no left assigned for the div, I use `$('#').css('left');` to get the left value, but it shows auto.

How do I get the left value of the div.

Thanks
Jean

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The .css() command returns what the CSS setting is, so if you have 'auto' set, that is what you will see.

You can retrieve the computed position relative to the parent with `$('#').position().left;`, 'top' also is available from position(), if you want the value relative to the document use `$('#').offset().left`.

Comment: If you need the right position, then you can use `$('#').position().left + $('#').width()` usually, though if you need to take account of margins/padding you may need to use outerWidth().

Answer (score 7):

The [offset()](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) method tells you the actual position of the element relative to the document. See the example on the page that I linked to to see how they got the left and top values.

That is:

```
  var left = $('Your_selector').offset().left;
```

Comment: @orbling has the answer I require, it works with one line, this is document related, but I want it w.r.t the parent